# Joomla/Virtuemart scripts not working on the product detail view

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have a Joomla 2.5.20 site with VirtueMart 2.6.4. I'm creating a template that among other things uses jQuery and Bootstrap. While the site works well in general, including VM's cart, I'm facing problems with the product detail view: no script from VirtueMart seems to be working: if I click on a thumbnail image, it won't change the main image. If I click on the main image, it will open in a new window instead of opening with Fancybox. The rating control won't allow me to select a star to rate the product.

I've been searching all over and every answer I've come up with say it's a jQuery conflict. While jQuery (v. 1.8.0) is there, I don't see where the conflict could possibly be.

The site is: 
http://www.dailymood.com.mx

The URL to a sample where it's not working: 
http://www.dailymood.com.mx/catalog/mood/20014moodbarbcrh-detail

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to find the problem with Firebug?

Comment: Hi Lexib0y, yes, I tried with Firebug and with Chrome's tools as well. In the end I got rid of jQuery for that page and used MooTools (had to read a few tutorials), that solved my problem. Best regards!

Comment: Out of curiousity, are you using a plugin to determine per page if you want mootools or jquery? If not, check out plugins like jquery-easy.